# value from env not echoing

Tags: php, laravel

i have worked on laravel with quite some time now with laravel 5.0 to 5.8 i am currently using **laravel 5.7** in a project , i am declaring some constants in my env file but i am unable to print them in my controller here is constants in my env file

```
    APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:Qm/Xwz4V9oJLhlk8RiY4usy4cdruFHRTe8iYkj7suMs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://devmarketplace.finpay.pk
LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

#crm database
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=marketplacecrm
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

#marketplace database
LIVE_READ_DB_HOST=localhost
LIVE_WRITE_DB_HOST=localhost

#marketplace database
LIVE_DB_DATABASE=marketplace
LIVE_DB_USERNAME=root
LIVE_DB_PASSWORD=

#marketplace logs
LIVE_LOGS_DB_HOST=localhost
LIVE_LOGS_DB_DATABASE=marketplacelogs
LIVE_LOGS_DB_USERNAME=root
LIVE_LOGS_DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

PAYROLL_BANKS=http://devpayrollplus.finpay.pk/public/apiV2/
UNEEB=UNEEB
```

now i am accessing them in my controller like

```
public function index(){
        echo env("UNEEB");
        exit();
        return view("stores.stores");
    }
```

i have performed a number of steps after adding value in my env

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

but it still doesnt work, the funny part is i have another project on laravel 5.8 and it works fine over their, here is my composer.json and package.json in case something went wrong over their.

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "awobaz/compoships": "^1.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3",
        "donatello-za/rake-php-plus": "^1.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "genealabs/laravel-model-caching": "^0.3.6",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/telescope": "^1.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.1",
        "spatie/laravel-database-mail-templates": "^2.0",
        "spatie/laravel-fractal": "^5.4",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.29"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/GeneralHelper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Model\\": "app/Models",
            "Report\\": "app/Reports",
            "Settlement\\": "app/Settlements",
            "Batch\\": "app/Batches"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
        "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
        "datatables.net-autofill-bs4": "^2.3.2",
        "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.19",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.5.4",
        "datatables.net-colreorder-bs4": "^1.5.1",
        "datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4": "^3.2.6",
        "datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4": "^3.1.5",
        "datatables.net-keytable-bs4": "^2.5.0",
        "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.3",
        "datatables.net-rowgroup-bs4": "^1.1.0",
        "datatables.net-rowreorder-bs4": "^1.2.5",
        "datatables.net-scroller-bs4": "^1.5.1",
        "datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.2.7",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jshint": "^2.10.2",
        "mdbootstrap": "^4.7.0",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
        "vue": "^2.5.22",
        "vue-fullscreen": "^2.1.3",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^2.1.0",
        "vue2-daterange-picker": "^0.1.6",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using `php artisan serve` to run the project?

Comment: yes i am! but it doesn't work on localhost and demo environment as well

Comment: check the ans... you must have to kill the server and re-run `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 2):

## Follow these steps

Add your constant to **.env** like
`ADMIN_EMAIL=some@email.com`

Add the same to your `config/app.php`
`'admin_email' => env('ADMIN_EMAIL', 'default@email.com'),`

Retrieve your value
`{{config('app.admin_email')}}`

Comment: this was the solution i implemented but i was looking forward to use env

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have stopped the server once after new change in `.env` if you are using `php artisan serve` to load new changes.

Because default it run the configuration given at that time the server start.

So for loading each new changes from `.env` you must have to kill the process and re-run `php artisan serve`

**Edited:**

Also confirm, If there is any variable in `.env` contains `spaces or special charectors` make sure you have wrap them in `double quotes`.

Comment: @uneeb let me know if it helps!

Comment: !h thankyou for the reply i always do these steps while changing env it didnt worked

Comment: Please share your `.env` there might be something incorrect there with other values may conotains space or special charecter

Comment: If there is any variable like that.. make sure you have wrap-up that in `double quotes`.

Comment: it contains some confidential information, i will remove them and then add it

Comment: @uneebmeer try encapsulate these two values in double quotes. PAYROLL_BANKS="http://devpayrollplus.finpay.pk/public/apiV2/"
UNEEB="UNEEB"

Comment: And then try.... also try change the position of `UNEEB="UNEEB"` at top to make sure any other variable/values not causing issue.

Comment: APP_KEY and APP_URL is also encapsulated in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, those commands that you performed should've fixed your issue... Anyways, Laravel it's a bit sensitive with its .env file, so for your usage, I would change the approach of constants.

Laravel recommends only to use `env()` within the configuration files. Try use the `config()` helper in your code instead of `env()`. Move your constants into a new file and then you can call `config('blah-blah-name')` in your code.

Hope it will help.

LE: If you using `php artisan serve`, it might be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
 echo env("UNEEB")
```

while it is declared with 3 capital E's in your env file.

Comment: nice catch that was just a typo in the original env file it was correct